# Install Pygraphviz python

Tags: python, windows, installation, conda, pygraphviz

I tried to install pygraphviz on my laptop in two different way:

## 1) with conda:

`conda install -c alubbock pygraphviz.` It went all the way down and then

```
C:\>SET DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1

C:\>SET MSSdk=1

C:\>SET platform=

C:\>IF /I [AMD64] == [amd64] set "platform=true"

C:\>IF /I [] == [amd64] set "platform=true"

C:\>if defined platform (set "VSREGKEY=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0" )  ELSE (set "VSREGKEY=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0" )

C:\>for /F "skip=2 tokens=2,*" %A in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0" /v InstallDir') do SET "VSINSTALLDIR=%B"
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.

C:\>if "" == "" (set "VSINSTALLDIR=" )

C:\>if "" == "" (
ECHO "WARNING: Did not find VS in registry or in VS140COMNTOOLS env var - your compiler may not work"
 GOTO End
)
"WARNING: Did not find VS in registry or in VS140COMNTOOLS env var - your compiler may not work"
The system cannot find the batch label specified - End
```

## 2) with pip: `pip install pygraphviz`

it is saying requirement already satisfied but when run my python code I got the error:

```
ImportError: ('requires pygraphviz ', 'http://pygraphviz.github.io/')
```

Comment: Missing information we need: Your OS is Windows. **a) Did conda (or pip) already have pygraphviz installed? If yes to either/both, b) was that installed with user privileges, or administrator privileges? c) Can you uninstall them using the original command, then reinstall?** That is almost surely the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Is python and pip part of the same distribution in your system. It may be that you have multiple installations on your system and you pip might be related to a distribution that isnt the same as the one you are running your code in

Answer (score -1):

To force the installation you could uninstall first or use the -U (or --upgrade) parameter.

So, use one of these alternatives by using pip

```
pip uninstall pygraphviz
pip install pygraphviz
```

or

```
pip install -U pygraphviz
```

Hope it works